# To amazon or not to amazon

Tags: web-applications, architecture, amazon-web-services, hosting

I'm going to have a web project with guaranteed 200 000 visitors per 5 days.
The project is a New Year postcard site. The main page content will be 0.5MB to 1MB. But site will demonstrate a video of 10 to 20 MB.

I was planning to host it on a single VPS or on two VPS-s. One for main page and video loader and one for video. If video VPS is down - show some throbber or notification. But this heavy video scary me and the client. The first VPS with main page can guarantee up to 65000 requests per hour according to tests. The second one in best case can serve 5000-10000 requests per hour according to my estimations.

Should I go and order Amazon EC2? How can I calculate the price? Amazon calculators show me $30 per month.. that's extremly cheap for such a task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon's infrastructure is fine for tasks of this magnitude.  Consider using their CloudFront CDN to hold the actual video.

I suggest you spin up some instances and run a load test with your software to validate performance.  One great benefit of AWS over a VPS is that, if your instances are too slow, you can move up to larger and more powerful instance types with a few mouse clicks.  With a VPS, typically you're locked in by a contract.

Comment: yes, I understand all the limitations of the VPS. But for now it is the question of price, how to estimate the amazon bill more or less corerectly?

Comment: Their billing calculator is quite accurate http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html  You can do a load test using e.g. small instances.  If that is fast enough, use the calculator plugging in small instances.  If your testing indicates you need larger instances, plug in whatever instance size you determine.  Normally data transfer and data storage charges are very small compared to instance charges, so just plug in your best guess for that and you will not be very far off on the total charges.

Answer (score 2):

Estimate the Amazon bill using their calculator at http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html